# read excel and convert index to datatimeindex pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I read an excel in pandas like this

```
df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx", index_col=[0])
```

The dataframe look like this with the index containing a date and time and one column:

```
01.01.2015 00:15:00     47.2
01.01.2015 00:30:00     46.6
01.01.2015 00:45:00     19.4
01.01.2015 01:00:00     14.8
01.01.2015 01:15:00     14.8
01.01.2015 01:30:00     16.4
01.01.2015 01:45:00     16.2
...
```

I want to convert the index to a datatimeindex, I tried

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

and got: "ValueError: Unknown string format"

What is here the best way to convert the index to a datatime format containing date and tiem to use datetime based functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `format` - see http://strftime.org/:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

print (df)
                        a
2015-01-01 00:15:00  47.2
2015-01-01 00:30:00  46.6
2015-01-01 00:45:00  19.4
2015-01-01 01:00:00  14.8
2015-01-01 01:15:00  14.8
2015-01-01 01:30:00  16.4
2015-01-01 01:45:00  16.2
```

Comment: I tried that also, but got: "ValueError: unconverted data remains:  b" ???

Comment: It seems you have bad data - you can check all rows which cannot be converted to datetimeindex by `print (df[pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').to_series().isnull().values])`. What return it?

Comment: Thgen you can replace all bad values by `NaT` by `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
`

Comment: ok, you´re right, bad data, didnt recognize that. I deleted that data, now it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!